# Variable button label

Tags: php, zend-framework

I got a form for the registration of a user and use it as an edit-user-form, too.
Now I want to make this form more vabiable. That means in my case: I want to have a specific button label for the different actions.
If the form is called via RegisterAction, the label should be "Register" and if it's called via EditAction, it shall be "Update user". I tried some things but now I ran out of ideas.

Here is my code:

**CustomerController.php**

```
...
 public function registerAction(){
        $form = new Application_Form_Register();
        $request = $this->_request->getParams();

    if(isset($request['registerbtn']) && ($form->isValid($request) )){
        $customerModel = new Application_Model_Customer();
        $customerArr = $customerModel->setCustomer($request,true);
        $this->redirect('/customer/detail/id/'.$customerArr);
    }
    else{
        $this->view->form = $form;
        $this->view->button = "Register"; //TEST
    }
}

public function editAction(){
        $request = $this->_request->getParams();
        if(isset($request['id']) && !empty($request['id'])){
            $form = new Application_Form_Register();

            $form->addElement('hidden', 'id', array(
                'required'   => true,
                'value'      => $request['id'],
                'validators' => array(
                    $digits = new Zend_Validate_Digits()
                )
            ));

            if(isset($request['registerbtn']) && ($form->isValid($request) )){
                $customerModel = new Application_Model_Customer();
                $id = $customerModel->setCustomer($request,false);
                $this->redirect('/customer/detail/id/'.$id);
            }else{
                $modelResult = new Application_Model_Customer();
                $customer = $modelResult->getCustomer($request['id']);
                $cArr = $customer->toArray();
                $form->populate($cArr);

                $this->view->form = $form;
                $this->view->button = "Update user"; //TEST
            }
        }else{
            $this->redirect('/');
        }
}
...
```

**The views**

```
// register.phtml - begin
<h2>Registration</h2>
<?php
    $this->headTitle('Registration');

    $button = $this->button; //TEST
    $this->form->button = $button; //TEST

    echo $this->form;
    echo $this->error;?>
// register.phtml - end

// edit.phtml - begin
<?php
    echo $this->headline;
    $this->headTitle('Update user');

    $button = $this->button; //TEST
    $this->form->button = $button; //TEST

    echo $this->form;
?>
// edit.phtml - end
```

**And the form**

```
    //
    ...
    $this->addElement('submit', 'registerbtn', array(
        'ignore'   => true,
        'label'    => $button, //TEST
        'decorators' => $this->buttonDecorators,
    ));
    ...
```

I fear that this is totally wrong but I don't know how to do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
if ($cas1)
    $form->getElement('submit')->setLabel('cas1');
else
    $form->getElement('submit')->setLabel('cas2');
```

Comment: I tried "$form->getElement('registerbtn')->setLabel('Register');" and it works perfect. Thank you very much. =)